# Refactor function with for loop, multiples if else statement and incrementation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, refactoring

How can I refactor the following function?

So basically I have a table of data like this:

```
Date        Signups 
4/22/2018   1,119   
4/21/2018   1,269   
4/20/2018   1,734   
4/19/2018   1,063   
4/18/2018   1,070   
4/17/2018   1,545   
4/16/2018   1,921   
4/15/2018   1,946   
4/14/2018   1,235   
4/13/2018   1,319   
4/12/2018   1,296   
4/11/2018   1,779   
4/10/2018   1,205
```

And I'm trying to get this:

```
This week, Previous week, Last previous week, Second previous week, etc...
848        848            848                 etc...
683        683            683                 etc...
842        842            687                 etc...
687        687            683                 etc...
948        948            627                 etc...
627        627            948                 etc...
687        687            687                 etc...
```

So I'm looping through each row of the initial table and creating buckets based on date.

I've created a small helper function but I'm pretty sure that this can be refactored much more efficiently.

```
function helper(Row, Col, i, weekStart, WeekEnd) {

    //set headers row 
    sheet_chart.getRange(1, Col + 1, 1, 1).setValue(DateFormat(addDays(selectedDate, weekStart)) + "-" + DateFormat(selectedDate, WeekEnd));

    //set conversions
    sheet_chart.getRange(Row, Col + 1, 1, 1).setValue(val[i][2]);

}


for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {

    if (val[i][0] <= selectedDate && val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 7))

    {
        row1++
        var Col = 8
        helper(row1, Col, i, 7, 0);
        sheet_chart.getRange(row1, Col, 1, 1).setValue(val[i][0]);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 14) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 7))

    {
        row2++
        var Col = 9
        helper(row2, Col, i, 14, 7);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 21) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 14))

    {
        row3++
        var Col = 10
        helper(row3, Col, i, 21, 14);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 28) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 21))

    {
        row4++
        var Col = 11
        helper(row4, Col, i, 28, 21);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 35) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 28))

    {
        row5++
        var Col = 12
        helper(row5, Col, i, 35, 28);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 42) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 35))

    {
        row6++
        var Col = 13
        helper(row6, Col, i, 42, 35);
    } else if (val[i][0] > addDays(selectedDate, 49) && val[i][0] <= addDays(selectedDate, 42))

    {
        row7++
        var Col = 14
        helper(row7, Col, i, 49, 42);
    } else if (val[i][0] < addDays(selectedDate, 42))

    {
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue("Last 50 days and more")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What's the relation between the database table and the output you want? Buckets?

Comment: Yes. It is for a specific data viz tool. I need to have conversions for each previous week (based on a date for the initial week) in separate columns (with a row for each day of the week)... does it make sense?

Comment: Ah, so in the output the day of the week is vertical? What is the first day? Monday or sunday? Why only 6 days in a week?

Comment: Monday and should be 7 days; I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a table with all the signups of every day, and in different columns depending on the week.

The `getDay()` [function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) returns a number from 0 to 6, being 0 Sunday, 1 Monday, etc.

Knowing this, we can do the following:

```
function calculate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Sheet name');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var dates = sheet.getRange("A2:A"+lastrow).getValues();
  var signups = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastrow).getValues();
  sheet.getRange("A2:B"+lastrow).clearFormat().clear(); //Clears the cell if you will use the columns A and B to show the result

  var row = 2;

  if (new Date(dates[0]).getDay() == 1){ //If the first day is monday, start at "column 0" as we will add 1 later
      var column = 0;
  }
    else {
      var column = 1;
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){

    var weekday = new Date(dates[i]).getDay();

    if (weekday == 1){
      row = 2; //If it's monday we reset the row index.
      column++;
    } 
    sheet.getRange(1, column).setValue("Week " + column)
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(signups[i]);

    row++;

  }
}
```